How To Find The Closest Value In An Array?
I have made a Node.js server which pulls data from an API every second and stores it if there is a change in the data. The "data" of the site is an object which also has the timestamp of that data. If I save this timestamp in an array, how do I find the one closest to any timestamp that I enter?
I do not know if this is optimized, if it isn't please provide a solution or method which is more optimized.

Sort the array by timestamp, binary search for the closest?

the array itself is made of timestamps
for eg
[time1,time2,time3.......]

OK, so sort it and then binary search. Optionally for values t1,t2,t2,..., tN store as interval pairs (-inf,t1), [t1,t2), [t2, t3), ..., [tN, +inf) and binary search to find an enclosing interval.

im sorry i understood nothing whatsoever from your comment, can you please elaborate

I'm new to StackOverflow too, and my english maybe be poor, so sorry for the mistakes.
I don't know if it is optimized, but you can create a variable called like "closest = null" and another called "difference = 0", then loop over your array subtracting each timestamp from your entered timestamp.
For each iteration check if the value of substraction is bigger than the actual value in variable "distance", if it is, change the variable to that value and the variable "closest" to the timestamp that you subtract, else continue the loop.
Something like:
//initializing example array
const list = [];

data1 = new Date();
data1.setFullYear(2024);
data1.setMonth(7);

data2 = new Date();
data2.setFullYear(2024);
data2.setMonth(8);

data3 = new Date();
data3.setFullYear(2024);
data3.setMonth(9);

list.push(data1,  data2,  data3);

//initialize variables to store the closest date and the difference between the entered date and the closest date
closest = null;
diff = 0;

//iterate over the array of dates
list.forEach((stamp) => {
    //that will be the entered date you want, im using the current date
    const data_hoje = new Date(); 
    
    //if the closest date is null, set the current date as the closest date and calculate the difference between the current date and the closest date
    if(closest == null) {
        closest = stamp
        diff = data_hoje - stamp
    } else {
        //if the difference between the current date and the closest date is less than the current difference, update the closest date and the difference
        if(data_hoje - stamp < diff) {
            closest = stamp
            diff = data_hoje - stamp
        }
    }
    
})

//print the closest date - response is the timestamp of date3
console.log(closest);


my array has atleast 1000+ timestamps at once all in numerical format
i don't need the current date, i want it to give the closest value to my input number
and what does "hoje" mean?

Yeah, i used current date just for example, it can be any date you want. Maybe you can make an input system and trow the input in that variable. I put only 3 date on array just for example too. What it prints is the date closest to the input date, in this case, the input date is today, so it prints the closest date to today. You can use "stamp.getTime()" to get the numerical value, then if your input is numerical too it will work anyway. "hoje" is "today" in portuguese lol. Sorry if I misunderstood your question
